# Facebook iOS LoginButton SDK only uses Web or System Authentication; never uses FB app

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I'm testing Facebook single sign on in the following scenarios

- When an account is logged in via Settings\Facebook
- When an account is logged in via Safari
- When an account is logged in via the local app.

The last test, when the Facebook app is installed and has valid credentials, never seems to work.

The only options that seem to work is when Safari is logged out OR the settings\Facebook system isn't logged in either.

I don't want to cause the user to ever enter a password, especially into a Web browser (or something that looks like one).

**Question**

- How do I get iOS SDK to authenticate using the installed, working Facebook app?

**Research**

I've tested all forms of Facebook authentication, where I set the loginButton to all [loginBehaviors](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginButton/), and even a null parameter

```
        loginButton = new LoginButton (new CGRect (48, 0, 218, 46)) {
            // LoginBehavior = 
            //  LoginBehavior.Browser   // safari
            //  LoginBehavior.Native    // safari 
            // LoginBehavior.Web        // popup (doesn't feel secure)
            //LoginBehavior.SystemAccount  // SYSTEM, if fail then Safari... ignore app
        };
```

Comment: It is because changes Apple did in iOS9

Comment: @WizKid What changes Apple did in iOS9? Do you have any reference?

Comment: Apple changed so the user have to approve if you open another app

Comment: I'm not getting prompted to open the other app

Answer (score 0):

Have you whitelisted Facebook apps in the info.plist file?

From Facebook Docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9):

> If you use any of the Facebook dialogs (e.g., Login, Share, App
>   Invites, etc.) that can perform an app switch to Facebook apps, you
>   will need to update your application's plist to handle the changes to
>   canOpenURL described in
>   https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=703.